# Output of "${OSTYPE:6}" on old releases of Mac OS X

Tags: macos

I'm writing a shell script that I want to be theoretically compatible with very old versions of Mac OS X (I say "theoretically", because I lack any super-old machines to actually test with). The script uses the output of `${OSTYPE:6}` to determine which release of Mac OS X it's running on.

On a machine running 10.13 High Sierra, `echo ${OSTYPE:6}` returns `17`. On a machine running 10.10 Yosemite, it returns `14`. Logic thus suggests that the command would output "15" on 10.11 and "16" on 10.12.

(This is useful, because it allows me to include lines like `if [[ ${OSTYPE:6} -ge 14 ]]; then DoThing; fi` to run `DoThing` on any system running Yosemite and newer.)

Does this pattern hold for old releases as well? For example, would the command return "4" on the original 10.0?

I ask because, well, it would be odd to start at 4, so I'm worried that somewhere in history, the number was incremented by a point update.

Comment: For some older versions, it returns a dotted number pair. On OS X 10.6.8 I get "10.0", and on OS X 10.3.9 I get "7.0". Unfortunately, that means `bash` can't do numeric comparisons on it in these versions.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Ugh, thank you for the heads up! I have now made the check a much less clean `if (( $(echo "${OSTYPE:6} > 13" | bc -l) )); then DoThing; fi`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That sounds very much like it's returning the Darwin version.

Your theory works well from 10.15 Mojave [18] back to 10.2 Jaguar [6] but fails before that, as Darwin was 1.x.x at that point.

There's a full list at [Wikipedia - macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS#Release_history)

Answer (score 3):

> On a machine running 10.13 High Sierra, echo ${OSTYPE:6} returns 17...

Here's an old PowerMac G5 running OS X 10.5 circa 2009:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.17(1)-release (powerpc-apple-darwin9.0)

$ sh --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.17(1)-release (powerpc-apple-darwin9.0)

$ echo ${OSTYPE:6}
9.0

$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.5.8
BuildVersion:   9L31a

$ system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: Mac OS X 10.5.8 (9L31a)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 9.8.0
      Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
      Boot Mode: Normal
      Computer Name: PowerMac
      User Name: Jeffrey (jwalton)
      Time since boot: 66 days 3:46
```

---

I've never used `if [[ ${OSTYPE:6} -ge 14 ]]; then DoThing; fi`. However, I've used similar to this in shell scripts and Makefiles:

```
IS_OLD_DARWIN=$(system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType 2>/dev/null | grep -i -c -E "OS X 10\.[0-5]")
if [[ "$IS_OLD_DARWIN" -ne 0 ]]; then DoThing; fi
```

---

I can provide remote SSH access to the PowerMac. I use it for testing open source libraries, like Crypto++ and OpenSSL. Email me at *noloader, gmail account* if you want access.

As far as I know, the oldest version of Bash you can get your hands on for testing is Bash 2.x circa 2004. Download Fedora 1 from [/pub/archive/fedora/linux/core](https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/core/).

Comment: Thank you! I won't be taking you up on the ssh offer right now—I'm not *quite* dedicated enough to this project—but I really appreciate it!

Comment: General question—do you not have any security concerns about leaving an outdated OS accessible via SSH? Have you done anything special to harden the system?

Comment: @Wowfunhappy - The box is mostly safe from network attackers. The box is sitting behind my IPFire firewall. The only port accessible to the outside world is SSH. SSH is updated regularly; and I maintain [Build Scripts](https://github.com/noloader/Build-Scripts) for this scenario. The local attacker can do more damage. But folks with accounts on the box don't have to work too hard since I am happy to offer them root access if they ask for it or need it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a 10.0 machine to test on, but on 10.3 and 10.5 machines, `echo ${OSTYPE:6}` returns a blank line (`$OSTYPE` on both is `darwin`); on 10.6, it returns `10.0`.

(Incidentally, your shell script would need to explicitly invoke `bash`.  The default shell on very old versions of OSX is `tcsh`, which doesn't understand the `${OSTYPE:6}` syntax.)

Answer (score 1):

Apple stores version information in Core Foundation and here is the source code showing how they build to each version.

- https://opensource.apple.com/source/DarwinTools/DarwinTools-1/sw_vers.c.auto.html

I’d use `sw_vers` to get your version information if you’re scripting rather than use `uname` or other variables.

Comment: Would `sw_vers` work in a shell script?

Comment: It’s in the path of all the shipping shells on macOS / OS X / Darwin, so yes @Wowfunhappy it will work well.

Comment: Thanks. I remember why I didn't use this now—because it doesn't output an integer like `OSTYPE:6`, I can't use a simple -ge / -le checks to isolate "this version and everything newer/older"

Comment: @Wowfunhappy Aren’t the build numbers monotonically increasing and sortable as strings? I think there’s an entire python library / module to handle this iirc - it’s pyfacts - https://github.com/timsutton/python-macadmin-tools

Comment: Ah, Finlay Doobie, who fixed a bug in OS X that escaped Apple's software engineers for over a year - https://www.wired.com/2002/03/apple-ousts-coder-for-being-young/

Comment: Woah @fd0 I had no idea of the notoriety.